# Page Navigation for showOtherOption(true)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

We have used Google Apps Script to generate a form instead of using the UI to create a form directly.

We have set a multiple choice question and would like to add an 'other' option to this list where the user can type in details of what the 'other' option is (as opposed to a static 'Other' option).

Go-To-Page navigation is fine for all other options, but **is there a way to set a 'go-to-page' navigation for this showOtherOption(true)** ?

```
var TechOpsReqDeets = form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle('TechOps request details')
    .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
var TechOpsReqSelect = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
TechOpsReqSelect.setTitle('Request type');
    var tADCs = TechOpsReqSelect.createChoice('Adserving/data 
    costs',TechOpsAdservingDataCosts)
    var tCIs = TechOpsReqSelect.createChoice('Creative 
    issue',TechOpsCreativeIssue)
    var tOs = TechOpsReqSelect.showOtherOption(true);
          TechOpsReqSelect.setChoices([tADCs,tCIs,tOs])
```

Comment: Please add the code you're using to generate the form so we can help mor effectively.

Comment: @BrianBennett Thanks for your suggestion - I've added part of the code used to generate the form. 

The first two choices and their corresponding go-to-page navigations to the page break items (TechOpsAdservingDataCosts and TechOpsCreativeIssue - not included here) appear to work. 

I cannot see any way to add page navigation for the showOtherOption(true).

Comment: unfortunately, [getGotoPage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice#getgotopage)  is available to Choice objects and not to showOtherOption(true) property.

Comment: Despite of its Web UI has dropdown to select go to page, its GAS does not...